# What will be the mongoengine equivalent of following mongodb query

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Following mongodb query gets me the expected result

```
db.business.distinct(
     'location',
      {
       city:'CityName'
      }
).sort()
```

I need help in creating an equivalent for the same in Django. Im using mongoengine with Django.

Comment: It looks like this question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12007726/how-to-query-for-distinct-results-in-mongodb-with-python