# MongoDB Collection with Non-repeated field value

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

So I'm rather new to MongoDB. Here is an imaginary database with the following format.

```
{
    "_id": "message_id", 
    "headers": {
        "from": <from_email>,
        "to": <to_email>, 
        "timestamp": <timestamp>
    },   
    "message": {
        "message": <the message contents>, 
        "signature": <signature contents>
    }
}
```

Suppose all emails received are inserted into it and sometimes emails are double sent. How can one return a collection of emails from an author without any double sends.

I thought this might do it but it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
db.mycoll.find({"headers.from": <authorname>}).distinct("message.message")
```

Edit: 
Please excuse me, It seems I have been making some kind of typo, the above query works, but it only returns messages.messages without the Headers, How would I keep the headers intact as well?

Comment: What's the issue when you run that?
[distinct()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) is a function that collection objects have - it looks like [find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) returns a list, not a mongodb collection. I'll try running it in a few..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to really determine from your question which part is the "duplicate" or therefore should be unique. It stands to reason though that things such as the message "_id" and "timestamp" are not going to duplicate, so this only really leaves the message content, with the possible additional paranoia of that message being "from" the same person.

Document reshaping is generally best handled by the [aggregation framework](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "message": "$message.message", "from": "$headers.from" },
        "message_id": { "$first": "$_id" },
        "headers": { "$first": "$headers" },
        "message": { "$first": "$message" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$message_id",
        "headers": 1,
        "message": 1
    }}
])
```

The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) will filter out any matching message content with the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operations selecting only the "first" found item for the matching field on the document grouping boundary.

There is an assumption in here that the existing order is by "timestamp" but if not then you might want to apply a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) as the first pipeline stage before the others:

```js
{ "$sort": { "headers.timestamp": 1 } }
```

The final [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) really just restores the original document form and removes the "grouping key" that was supplied earlier. Just prettier than duplicating information and/or putting things out of place.

Comment: I was wondering if `_id` + `.aggregate` is the generally accepted way to guarantee distinctness? (more detailed formulation in my answer based on yours)

Comment: `_id` is a unique key therefore whole document is implied as well as being distinct. I can also say how do get to an "answer" based on what is provided by someone else? I'll leave that in general as you needed to gain the knowledge from somewhere. The second point is If other answers (and there are many) do not meet what you are asking then your question is not clear enough for people to follow. Please learn to give credit where it is due. Who answered your question as presented really?

Comment: Your answer didn't quite give me what I was looking for but I've marked it as correct since it gives the generally applicable technique. Regarding `_id` - is there way to make a "custom unique key" that is not `_id` or must `_id` be used to in aggregate to guarantee uniqueness? P.S. I was by no way trying to take credit for your answer, I just wanted some clarity on the above question and the comment space did not seem like enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `distinct()` to return an array of distinct messages from a specific author as follows:

```
db.collection.distinct('message.message', {"headers.from": <authorname>})
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work exactly - "distinct() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given".

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is not currently implemented (at least as far as I know). One work around would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12007907/926321)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([
{
  $match:{"headers.from": <authorname>}
},{
   $group:{
   _id:"$headers.from",
   "message":{$addToSet:"$message.message"}
}
}

])
```

Comment: Duplicate messages aren't excluded from this set.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Neil Lunn's answer above:
I think one can do

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"headers.from": <from email>} } ,
{"$group": { "_id": "$message.message"}, 
"headers": {"$first": "$headers"}, 
"signature": {"$first": "$message.signature"},
 "message_id": "$_id" }}, 
{"$project" : { "_id": "$message_id", 
"headers": "$headers", 
"message": { "message": "$_id", "signature": "$signature" } } }])
```

Since `_id` must be unique the consequence is that duplicate messages will not make the list, and then `$project` will restructure it to the original object structure with correct key names.

I guess I only have one question in this regard - is there a way to force uniqueness without aggregating into `_id` or is this generally considered the correct way to do it in `MongoDB` ?